# Left join not working in NHibernate LINQ to entities

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to do `left-join` using LINQ to NHibernate.

I have the following code:

```
var query = from formdat in _formDatRepository.Table
            join proddat in _prodDatRepository.Table 
            on formdat.prodcode equals proddat.prodcode into proddats
            select new Model
            {
                   Brand = formdat.brand,
                   Generic = string.Empty
            }
result = query.ToList();
```

This is throwing the exception:

> The method or operation is not implemented.

Stack trace:

> at NHibernate.Linq.CacheableExpressionNode.Resolve(ParameterExpression inputParameter, Expression expressionToBeResolved, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
>      at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.ExpressionResolver.GetResolvedExpression(Expression unresolvedExpression, ParameterExpression parameterToBeResolved, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
>      at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.JoinExpressionNode.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(ExpressionResolver r)
>      at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.ResolvedExpressionCache`1.GetOrCreate(Func`2 generator)
>      at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.JoinExpressionNode.CreateJoinClause(ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
>      at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.GroupJoinExpressionNode.ApplyNodeSpecificSemantics(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
>      at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.MethodCallExpressionNodeBase.Apply(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
>      at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Boolean filter)
>      at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
>      at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
>      at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
>      at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at MasterCare.MIMS.Australia.Services.MIMSService.Search(String key)

**Note:**

There are no navigation properties since there are no foreign key relationships between the tables.